# Открыть меню по клику

Tags: javascript

У меня есть меню. По клику оно не открывается, но вот по второму клику оно открывается. Что делать? Помогите, пожалуйста.

```js
function upload() {
  var dropDown = document.getElementById("drop-upload");
  if (dropDown.style.display == "none") {
    dropDown.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    dropDown.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#drop-upload {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 15%;
  cursor: default;
}

.upload {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#upload-html {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mnu-code">
  <li class="upload" onclick="upload()">Загрузить
    <div id="drop-upload">
      <a id="upload-html" onclick="openFileHtml()">Загрузить файл Html</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть объяснение на [английской версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083872/grabbing-style-display-property-via-js-only-works-when-set-inline).

Что бы из js получить стиль нужно использовать window.getComputedStyle (для большинства браузеров) или element.currentStyle (Internet Explorer).

Ниже код поправил, до этого условие просто уходило в else.

Думаю идея будет понятна, что бы исправить.

```js
function upload() {
    var dropDown = document.getElementById("drop-upload"); 

    if (dropDown.currentStyle) {
        var displayStyle = dropDown.currentStyle.display;
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        var displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(dropDown, null).getPropertyValue("display");
    }

    if (displayStyle == "none") {
      dropDown.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
      dropDown.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
#drop-upload {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9000;
    background-color: black;
    height: 50px;
    width: 15%;
    cursor: default;
}
.upload {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#upload-html {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mnu-code">
<li class="upload" onclick="upload()">Загрузить
    <div id="drop-upload">
         <a id="upload-html" onclick="openFileHtml()">Загрузить файл Html</a>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Изначально у блока `drop-upload` нет атрибута `style`, поэтому условие не срабатывает первый раз.

```js
function upload() {
  var dropDown = document.getElementById("drop-upload");
  console.log(dropDown.style.display);
  if (dropDown.style.display == "none" || !dropDown.style.display) { //добавлено условие !dropDown.style.display
    dropDown.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    dropDown.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#drop-upload {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 15%;
  cursor: default;
}

.upload {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#upload-html {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mnu-code">
  <li class="upload" onclick="upload()">Загрузить
    <div id="drop-upload">
      <a id="upload-html" onclick="openFileHtml()">Загрузить файл Html</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Также можно использовать метод [getComputedStyle()](http://theory.phphtml.net/javascript/dom/getComputedStyle.html)

```js
function upload() {
  var dropDown = document.getElementById('drop-upload');
  if (window.getComputedStyle(dropDown).getPropertyValue('display') == 'none') {
    dropDown.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    dropDown.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#drop-upload {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 15%;
  cursor: default;
}

.upload {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#upload-html {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mnu-code">
  <li class="upload" onclick="upload()">Загрузить
    <div id="drop-upload">
      <a id="upload-html" onclick="openFileHtml()">Загрузить файл Html</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```